# Deploy Laravel app to Godaddy hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I kept searching today for a proper guide on how to deploy my laravel app to a godaddy hosting but no luck so far..
I followed this https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd

The problem is that when I open the website I get some weird error from laravel. Check the image. As you can see, laravel is still pointing to my local folder somehow..
[image]

I changed the path in the index.php file like so:

```
require __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../project/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The 'project' folder is at the same level as public_html folder. What can be the problem here?

Comment: you don't need to change anything in server, none of change in `index.php`, just upload whole code.

Comment: Upload the whole code to public html? Won't that have some security issues?

Comment: Why would it have? Laravel is already having many security concepts, and what security you break here if you upload code to `public_html`?

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: I'm getting You don't have permission to access / on this server. I tried to move .htaccess from public folder to public_html but same error.

Comment: whoa, just put whole code without any change and point your domain into laravel public folder.

Comment: @OvidiuG If you dont want to place all you file under public_html folder here is a good link you can follow https://blog.kongnir.com/2015/09/25/setting-up-laravel-5-on-shared-hosting-server/ I have applied this same link so I works

Comment: See this answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57619997/10302693